# C++: передать кусок кода в функцию

Tags: c++

Можно ли в C++ передать в качестве аргумента кусок кода, а потом выполнить? Например, как в JS:

```
someFunction("test", function(){ console.log("test"); });
```

Comment: Что значит "кусок кода"? Это фактически и есть функция.

Comment: Простите, как должно быть?

Comment: Так или еще как-то?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В C++11 появились лямбда-функции и стало возможным делать вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void do_stuff(char *s, std::function<void(char)> f) {
    while(*s != '\0')
        f(*s++);
}

int main() {
    do_stuff("Hello World!", [](char c){ std::cout << c; });
    return 0;
}
```

---

Вариант на C89 с указателями на функции:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void do_stuff(char *s, void(*f)(char)) {
    while(*s != '\0')
        f(*s++);
}

void print(char c) {
    putchar(c);
}

int main() {
    do_stuff("Hello World!", print);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А есть возможность сделать это без `<functional>`?

Comment: Собственно, и задолго до C++11, в совсем младенческом C, можно было использовать указатели на функцию.

Comment: @klopp Можно, но я привёл на лямбдах как раз чтобы быть похожим на приведенный код. А передавать указатели на функции можно было ещё во времена C и Фортрана (хотя тут и не уверен насколько давно появилось).

Comment: Я отвечал на `без <functional>` :) Но что на самом деле надо автору вопроса - как обычно, покрыто тайной. Не исключено, что речь о праздном любопытстве или абстрактном "просто хочу как там". А зачем - нужно под пытками вытягивать :-)

Comment: @klopp Ааа. )) Я вообще изначально думал про рефлексию.

Comment: Без `<functional>` просто смените аргумент у функции на: `void do_stuff(char *s, void(*f)(char))`

Comment: `void(*f)(char)` - мне кажется, или приведение лямбды к такому возможно только в Си++14 и то не всегда?

Answer (score 1):

В С++ и С это было из начала времен, называется указатель  на функцию.